# Error instantiating servlet class [MyServlets.add]

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, web-applications

I am new to java web world and I am trying to deploy a simple web application using netbeans 12.3 .
I started with a simple addition form in my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Start Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="add" method="get">
            
            Number 1 : <input type="text" name="no1">  <br> <br>
            
            Number 2 : <input type="text" name="no2"> <br> <br>  
            
            <input type="submit" name="btnadd" value="Add" > 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my web.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="webapp" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>MyServlets.add</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            20000
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

My servlet add is inside the folder MyServlets in Sources Packages
I am using Tomcat 10.0 to deploy the web project but when i m in the index page and i click the button add after entering the two numbers i get an error

[image]

Here is how the files are organized in the project folder :

[image]

Comment: The stack trace says: **jakarta**.servlet.ServletException: [...] NoClassDefFoundError: **javax** /servlet/http/HttpServlet. You have probably messed the dependencies, compiling against the older javax namespace but running with the newest jakarta namespace.

Comment: How do i fix it ?